# Prevent reordering on Xceed DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I'm trying to cancel the reordering / drag and drop feature for some of the columns in a xceed datagrid (Community ed) grid (http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid)

What I have done so far is to listen to the PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp / Down event. I can then on Down set handled = true and user can do nothing with the column (no sorting or anything) or on Up, check if IsBeingDragged is true. But if I set e.Handled then, the column stays in a dragging mode. What I Want to do is to cancel the whole dragging and place the column back to it's original place, or (if possible) as close to the dropped column as possible.

Can anyone guide me?

```
private void ColumnManagerCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Check that the Original Source is a ColumnManagerCell
   if (sender.GetType() == typeof(Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.ColumnManagerCell))
   {
       ColumnManagerCell col = sender as ColumnManagerCell;
       if (col.IsBeingDragged)
       {
            // user attempted to move the column to a new location, or to the GroupByControl area
            e.Handled = true;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation of the Xceed DataGrid:

http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfDataGrid/#Grouping_Data.html

```
<Grid xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid"
  xmlns:d="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=PresentationFramework"
  xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase">
  <Grid.Resources>
    <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs_orders"
                                Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current},
                                                  Path=Orders}">
      <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="ShipCountry" Direction="Ascending"/>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="ShipCity" Direction="Ascending"/>
      </xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
      <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <xcdg:DataGridGroupDescription PropertyName="ShipCountry"/>
        <xcdg:DataGridGroupDescription PropertyName="ShipCity"/>
      </xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
   </xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource>
 </Grid.Resources>
 <xcdg:DataGridControl x:Name="OrdersGrid"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs_orders}}">      
   <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
     <xcdg:Column FieldName="ShipCountry" VisiblePosition="0"/>
     <xcdg:Column FieldName="ShipCity" VisiblePosition="1"/>
   </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
   <xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
     <xcdg:TableView FixedColumnCount="2" UseDefaultHeadersFooters="False">
       <xcdg:TableView.FixedHeaders>
         <DataTemplate>
           <xcdg:GroupByControl AllowSort="False" AllowGroupingModification="False"/>
         </DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
          <xcdg:ColumnManagerRow AllowSort="False" AllowColumnReorder="False"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </xcdg:TableView.FixedHeaders>
    </xcdg:TableView>
  </xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
</xcdg:DataGridControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: But setting AllowColumnReorder=False prevents all columns from reorder. What I want is so all but the fixed columns can be reordered. So column 1 and 2 (for example) may not be draged to a new place, but column 5 may be placed as column 3. What I can see in your code, this prevents all reordering or am I missing something?